# How to replace for loop in python with map transformation in pyspark where we want to compare previous row and current row with multiple conditions

Tags: pyspark, rdd

just dragged in a road block kind situation while applying map function on pyspark dataframe and need your help in coming out of this.

Though problem is even more complicated but let me simplify it with below example using dictionary and for loop, and need solution in pyspark.

Here example of python code on dummy data, I want same in pyspark map transformation with when, clause using window or any other way.

Problem - I have a pyspark dataframe with column name as keys in below dictionary and want to add/modify section column with similar logic applied in for loop in this example.

```python
record=[
{'id':xyz,'SN':xyz,'miles':xyz,'feet':xyz,'MP':xyz,'section':xyz},
{'id':xyz,'SN':xyz,'miles':xyz,'feet':xyz,'MP':xyz,'section':xyz},
{'id':xyz,'SN':xyz,'miles':xyz,'feet':xyz,'MP':xyz,'section':xyz}
]

last_rec='null'
section=0
for cur_rec in record:
    if lastTrack != null:
        if (last_rec.id != cur_rec.id | last_rec.SN != cur_rec.SN):
            section+=1

        elif (last_rec.miles == cur_rec.miles & abs(last_rec.feet- cur_rec.feet) > 1):
            section+=1

        elif (last_rec.MP== 555 & cur_rec.MP != 555):
            section+=1

        elif (abs(last_rec.miles- cur_rec.miles) > 1):
            section+=1


    cur_rec['section']= section
    last_rec = cur_rec
```

Comment: What's `lastTrack != null:`? Did you mean `last_rec is not None`? Also it would be helpful to have an example where all of the data isn't exactly the same. What is the desired output?

Comment: Yes, actually it is last_rec is not None, or last_rec != 'null'. Expected output is like this but here section value is changing based on gender column only while we have to apply conditions on multiple columns          +---+---+------+------+-------+
| SN|age|gender|  name|section|
+---+---+------+------+-------+
|  1| 45|     M|   Bob|      1|
|  2| 28|     M|Albert|      1|
|  3| 33|     F| Laura|      2|
|  4| 43|     F|Gloria|      2|
|  5| 18|     T|Simone|      3|
|  6| 45|     M|  Alax|      4|
|  7| 28|     M|Robert|      4|
+---+---+------+------+-------+

Answer (score 1):

Your window function is a cumulative sum of a boolean variable.
Let's start with a sample dataframe:

```py
import numpy as np
record_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [list(x) for x in zip(*[np.random.randint(0, 10, 100).tolist() for _ in range(5)])], 
    ['id', 'SN', 'miles', 'feet', 'MP'])
record_df.show()

    +---+---+-----+----+---+
    | id| SN|miles|feet| MP|
    +---+---+-----+----+---+
    |  9|  5|    7|   5|  1|
    |  0|  6|    3|   7|  5|
    |  8|  2|    7|   3|  5|
    |  0|  2|    6|   5|  8|
    |  0|  8|    9|   1|  5|
    |  8|  5|    1|   6|  0|
    |  0|  3|    9|   0|  3|
    |  6|  4|    9|   0|  8|
    |  5|  8|    8|   1|  0|
    |  3|  0|    9|   9|  9|
    |  1|  1|    2|   7|  0|
    |  1|  3|    7|   7|  6|
    |  4|  9|    5|   5|  5|
    |  3|  6|    0|   0|  0|
    |  5|  5|    5|   9|  3|
    |  8|  3|    7|   8|  1|
    |  7|  1|    3|   1|  8|
    |  3|  1|    5|   2|  5|
    |  6|  2|    3|   5|  6|
    |  9|  4|    5|   9|  1|
    +---+---+-----+----+---+
```

A cumulative sum is an ordered window function, therefore we'll need to use `monotonically_increasing_id` to give an order to our rows:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
record_df = record_df.withColumn(
    'rn', 
    psf.monotonically_increasing_id())
```

For the boolean variable we'll need to use `lag`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window
w = Window.orderBy('rn')
record_df = record_df.select(
    record_df.columns 
    + [psf.lag(c).over(w).alias('prev_' + c) for c in ['id', 'SN', 'miles', 'feet', 'MP']])
```

Since all the conditions yield the same result on `section`, it is an `or`clause:

```py
clause = (psf.col("prev_id") != psf.col("id")) | (psf.col("prev_SN") != psf.col("SN")) \
    | ((psf.col("prev_miles") == psf.col("miles")) & (psf.abs(psf.col("prev_feet") - psf.col("feet")) > 1)) \
    | ((psf.col("prev_MP") == 555) & (psf.col("MP") != 555)) \
    | (psf.abs(psf.col("prev_miles") - psf.col("miles")) > 1)
record_df = record_df.withColumn("tmp", (clause).cast('int'))
```

And finally for the cumulative sum

```py
record_df = record_df.withColumn("section", psf.sum("tmp").over(w))
```

Comment: @PrakashSingh, could you let us know if this answer helped you